# Cache flow in ViewModel

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, android-viewmodel, android-paging

I have a ViewModel

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class GreetingCoverScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(
  private val repository: PersonalizationRepository
) : ViewModel(){
  fun getIllustrations(occasionCode: String): Flow<PagingData<Illustration>> = repository.getIllustrations(
    occasionCode
  ).cachedIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

```kotlin
LazyColumn(
  state = listState,
  modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .weight(1f)
) {
  occasions.forEach{occasion ->
    item {
      IllustrationsItemView(
        occasion = occasion
      ){ illustration ->
        viewModel.onSelectIllustration(illustration)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```kotlin
@Composable
internal fun IllustrationsItemView(
  viewModel: GreetingCoverScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
  occasion: Occasion,
  onIllustrationsSelected: (illustration: Illustration) -> Unit
) {
  val pagingItems = viewModel.getIllustrations(
    occasionCode = occasion.code
  ).collectAsLazyPagingItems()
}
```

the function `getIllustrations` returns a `Flow` with a `PagingData` and I want to cache this in my `GreetingCoverScreenViewModel` but the flow is not cached when recomposing my screen it actually recreating new Flow

So how can I cache the flow that returned by a function? Please help

Answer (score 0):

The flow *is* cached, but you are creating new one on every recomposition. Use `remember` to call `getIllustrations` only when occasion code or viewModel change:

```kotlin
val pagingItems = remember(viewModel, occasion.code) {
    viewModel.getIllustrations(
        occasionCode = occasion.code
    )
}.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
```